# Issue in creating google cloud log sink in bigquery

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to create google cloud log sink for my organization for all project using the following command:

```
gcloud logging sinks create my-bq-sink bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/myproject/datasets/my_dataset 
--log-filter='logName: "logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"' 
--organization=1234 --include-children
```

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/best-practices-for-working-with-google-cloud-audit-logging

But I am getting error:

[image: sink error]

Comment: Don't use the command as is, substitute the value of fields with your project name and BQ dataset name.

Comment: Please don't post text as images

Comment: @KunalDeo Yes I did it obviously, Do you think any issue in logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity syntax?

Comment: Yes, could be some syntax I guess...try it out: `--log-filter logName: "logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"`

Comment: Does the same command still throw an error if you don't include the --organization and --include-children flags?
That way we could discard that the error is something specific to organizations. The command worked on the project level for me.

Comment: I was looking for all projects within the organization.

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue with that command? If so, trying to run the version of the command the way I suggested would help narrow down the cause of the issue to see if this only fails on the organization level. In case it works, you can delete the sink using ```gcloud logging sinks delete [SINK_NAME]```

Comment: Thanks. It worked with below command:
gcloud logging sinks create my_bq_sink \ bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/my_project/datasets/my_dataset \ --log-filter='resource.type="bigquery_resource" logName:("logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity" OR "logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access")' \ --organization=my_org_id --include-children